# how to Navigate to a particular bottom navigation item in a new page onpress of a button in the previous page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have many pages with the same bottom navigation bar title in my flutter app. For example, let's say I have two pages: A and B and page A doesn't have bottom navigation but page B has one with tree items. So I want to navigate from A to B but directly to the second or third item's index in bottom navigation items list.

Comment: you can pass the page number from first page to second one and then set it as current page index

Comment: I don't undestand what do you mean by "page number ..." but I have tried to change the current index value and it doesn't work. Thanks for your interest.